# convertir a csv un resultado de BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, csv, selenium, beautifulsoup

Estoy tratando de hacer un programita en Python3 que me recolecte la información de título, archivo, fecha y signatura, de cada elemento de esta página: http://pares.mcu.es/ParesBusquedas20/catalogo/contiene/425383, y que el resultado se guarde en un archivo csv.

Estoy utilizando BeautifulSoup, csv, y Selenium para automatizar la consulta por varias páginas y hasta el momento funciona.

```
url_entrada = "http://pares.mcu.es/ParesBusquedas20/catalogo/contiene/425383"
ident = "425383"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'bin/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(url_entrada)
```

Luego selecciono los elementos título, archivo, etc, con BeautifulSoup:

```
listado = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
caja = soup.select('table.displayTable tbody')
for box in caja:
    titulo = box.get_text('p.titulo a')
    tipo = box.get_text('p.tipo_archivo')
    date = box.get_text('p.fecha')
    sign = box.get_text('p.signatura')
    obtener = [titulo, tipo, date, sign]
    listado.append(obtener)
```

El listado me da este resultado:

```
[['\np.titulo a\np.titulo a\np.titulo a\xa0p.titulo aCarta de Juan Sánchez Bernardo de Quirós sobre subdelegado general de Cruzada\xa0p.titulo aArchivo: p.titulo aArchivo General de Indiasp.titulo aFechas: p.titulo a1759-07-23p.titulo aSignatura: p.titulo aFILIPINAS,301,N.50p.titulo a\np.titulo a\np.titulo a\np.titulo a\xa0p.titulo aCarta del agustino Benito de San Pablo sobre buen proceder de José Merino de Ribera\xa0p.titulo aArchivo: p.titulo aArchivo General de Indiasp.titulo aFechas: p.titulo a1757-06-28p.titulo aSignatura: p.titulo aFILIPINAS,301,N.29p.titulo a\np.titulo a\np.titulo a\np.titulo a\xa0p.titulo aCarta del agustino Juan Facundo Meseguer sobre buen proceder de José Merino de Ribera\xa0p.titulo aArchivo: p.titulo aArchivo General de Indiasp.titulo aFechas: p.titulo a1757-07-11p.titulo aSignatura: p.titulo aFILIPINAS,301,N.31 ...
```

Ahora, lo que trato es de convertirlo a csv:

```
if not os.path.exists('metadata_d/{}'.format(ident)):
    os.makedirs('metadata_d/{}'.format(ident))
with open('metadata_d/{}/{}-1.csv'.format(ident, ident), "w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerows(listado)
```

Pero el resultado es una celda por cada columna, y obviamente, lo que quiero es una celda por cada línea así:

```
"Carta de Juan Sánchez Bernardo de Quirós sobre subdelegado general de Cruzada","Archivo General de Indias","1759-07-23","FILIPINAS,301,N.50"
"Carta del agustino Benito de San Pablo sobre buen proceder de José Merino de Ribera","Archivo General de Indias","1757-06-28","FILIPINAS,301,N.29"
```

Les agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

encontré la solución :D

```
listado = []
tipolist = []
signalist = []
titulist = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
for em in soup("em"):
    soup.em.decompose()
caja = soup.select('table.displayTable tbody')
for box in caja:
    total = box.select('p.fecha')
    for columns in total:
        fecha = columns.get_text()
        listado.append(fecha)
    archi = box.select('p.tipo_archivo')
    for columns in archi:
        tip = columns.get_text()
        tipolist.append(tip)
    signa = box.select('p.signatura')
    for columns in signa:
        signat = columns.get_text()
        signalist.append(signat)
    titul = box.select('p.titulo a')
    for columns in titul:
        titu = columns.get_text()
        titulist.append(titu)
if not os.path.exists('metadata_d/{}'.format(ident)):
    os.makedirs('metadata_d/{}'.format(ident))
with open('metadata_d/{}/{}.csv'.format(ident, ident), "w", newline="") as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['Título','Fecha','Signatura','Archivo']
    writer_h = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer_h.writeheader()
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerows(zip(titulist,listado,signalist,tipolist))
```

Tal vez no sea la forma más elegante, pero funciona.